# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Ростенко сказал, ровнять с землей"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Ростенко сказал, ровнять с землей".

Comment: Нет, и так ясно. ))) Вы вообще что-нибудь слышали об оформлении  прямой речи? Интересная ведь, доложу вам, вещь.

Answer (score 2):

Запятой здесь нигде быть не может.
Либо "Ростенко **сказал ровнять** с землей" (составное сказуемое), либо "Ростенко сказал: "Ровнять с землей" (прямая речь).

Answer (score 2):

1) **Без запятой:** Ростенко сказал ровнять с землей.

Или, может быть,  "велел ровнять с землей" Смотрим в словаре: СКАЗАТЬ, 4. Разг. (нсв. говорить). Велеть; приказать. Вы **сказали мне явитьс**я утром.  Допускается в качестве  **разговорного варианта.**

2) **Есть еще варианты с СПП и БСП**, но они "длиннее":  Ростенко сказал, что надо ровнять с землей. Ростенко сказал: надо ровнять с землей.

3) **Рассмотрим  вариант разговорной речи с запятой**: Ростенко сказал, ровнять с землей. Здесь **вводное предложение** обособлено запятой. Очень короткая, но информативная фраза делится паузой на две части: кто сказал и что сказал.

4) **Примеры:** **Он сказал,** надо будет еще несколько раз обследование повторить, мой случай очень сложный. [Александра Маринина. Иллюзия греха (1996)]  Рубль, **он сказал**, надо дать раввину на извозчика. [Леонид Утесов. «Спасибо, сердце!» (1982)]

Вообще говоря, **оформление дословных высказываний имеет несколько вариантов,** выбор которых зависит от изображаемой ситуации, от стиля текста, от распространенности высказывания и т.д. В данном случае классический вариант прямой речи и использование вводного предложения    **никак не заменяют друг друга**. К примеру, возможен такой диалог на стройке:
― И что теперь будем делать?
― Ростенко сказал, ровнять с землей.